# Not defined Or zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let's say we play a game 9 times and I was asked to find the probability of $F_K$ which means the probability to succeed only at the $k^{th}$ try.

What can I say about $F_K$ for $k<0$ or $k>9$ is it 0 or not defined?

My professor said only one is true but I forgot which one of them and why is that.

Comment: What would it mean to say you first succeeded on the $-3^{rd}$ trial?

Comment: that's what I am asking is it 0 or not defined?

Comment: Well, if you can't say what it means then it is undefined.  By contrast, $F_{43}$ is perfectly well defined.  It is the probability that you lose the first $42$ games and win on your $43^{rd}$ attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that rolling a single standard die produces a $7$ is $0$. More generally, the probability of an impossible event is $0$. It may however *depend* on local definitions on what an *event* is in the given context.

In short, we consider a set of outcomes and an event is a subset of the set of outcomes. For a die, we *may* let $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the set of outcomes and the events "the roll is a six" and  "the roll is an odd number" then are the subsets $\{6\}$ and $\{1,3,5\}$, respectively. Is "the roll is a seven" an event? As stated, it certainly is not $\{7\}$ as this is not a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. But just as "the roll is odd" was interpreted as $\{1,3,5\}$ and not as $\{1,3,5,7,8,11,\ldots\}$, it is then correct to state that "the roll is a seven" is the empty event $\{\}$. As such it has probability $0$.

Alternatively, we could allow $7$ (and other values) as outcomes but with individual probability $0$. The result would not change - "roll is seven" now becomes the event $\{7\}$ but still has probability $0$.

With this philosophy in mind, the event "succeed only at $k$th try" for some impossible $k$ (negative, too big, not even an integer, ...) is an impossible event and hence has the (defined) probability $0$.